# Why are PIDs identical in docker stats for many containers?

Tags: docker

From the output of `docker stats`, I see that a lot of containers have the same PID. Why?

```
CONTAINER ID        NAME                CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
e12c382d6872        mesos-slave-58      0.10%               4.473MiB / 7.718GiB   0.06%               0B / 0B             0B / 8.19kB         12
50c03cb3fdf8        mesos-slave-55      0.08%               5.469MiB / 7.718GiB   0.07%               0B / 0B             36.9kB / 94.2kB     12
add886ad371e        mesos-slave-52      0.09%               5.285MiB / 7.718GiB   0.07%               0B / 0B             184kB / 94.2kB      12
78fe107d106c        mesos-slave-49      0.08%               6.742MiB / 7.718GiB   0.09%               0B / 0B             438kB / 61.4kB      12
b48f31fd0b18        mesos-slave-46      0.16%               17.28MiB / 7.718GiB   0.22%               0B / 0B             549kB / 61.4kB      33
1702bf0b014f        mesos-slave-43      0.07%               5.301MiB / 7.718GiB   0.07%               0B / 0B             328kB / 65.5kB      12
0d25eacfd8b6        mesos-slave-40      0.10%               7.27MiB / 7.718GiB    0.09%               0B / 0B             2.13MB / 217kB      12
1b43e01ebdc1        mesos-slave-37      0.08%               4.93MiB / 7.718GiB    0.06%               0B / 0B             238kB / 61.4kB      12
6bc2d5f10851        mesos-slave-34      0.09%               6.285MiB / 7.718GiB   0.08%               0B / 0B             180kB / 4.1kB       12
2c5b6d1bd2f2        mesos-slave-31      0.08%               4.387MiB / 7.718GiB   0.06%               0B / 0B             197kB / 4.1kB       12
ad028f43b30b        mesos-slave-28      0.07%               4.23MiB / 7.718GiB    0.05%               0B / 0B             139kB / 8.19kB      12
9d2d7e466150        mesos-slave-25      0.17%               18.09MiB / 7.718GiB   0.23%               0B / 0B             2.49MB / 184kB      34
d283840d591d        mesos-slave-22      0.09%               6.789MiB / 7.718GiB   0.09%               0B / 0B             365kB / 36.9kB      12
62db3581467e        mesos-slave-19      0.08%               4.645MiB / 7.718GiB   0.06%               0B / 0B             152kB / 36.9kB      12
605c26ea1428        mesos-slave-16      0.08%               5.922MiB / 7.718GiB   0.07%               0B / 0B             537kB / 65.5kB      12
a272df5e76b3        mesos-slave-13      0.07%               4.094MiB / 7.718GiB   0.05%               0B / 0B             45.1kB / 8.19kB     12
09cd22942e62        mesos-slave-10      0.07%               5.715MiB / 7.718GiB   0.07%               0B / 0B             147kB / 36.9kB      12
e13d2d953caa        mesos-slave-7       0.12%               4.023MiB / 7.718GiB   0.05%               0B / 0B             8.19kB / 8.19kB     12
bb90f3ae407a        mesos-slave-4       0.07%               3.969MiB / 7.718GiB   0.05%               0B / 0B             418kB / 8.19kB      12
34880c013c8c        mesos-slave-1       0.07%               4.074MiB / 7.718GiB   0.05%               0B / 0B             47.9MB / 4.1kB      12
```

Here's the command I used to start many containers with a loop:

```
docker run -d --net=host --name=mesos-slave-$node_id --privileged \
            -e MESOS_IP=$PC_IP \
            -e MESOS_HOSTNAME=$PC_IP \
            -e MESOS_PORT=$node_port \
            -e MESOS_MASTER=zk://$SERVER_IP:2181/mesos \
            -e MESOS_SWITCH_USER=0 \
            -e MESOS_CONTAINERIZERS=docker,mesos \
            -e MESOS_LOG_DIR=/var/log/mesos \
            -e MESOS_WORK_DIR=/var/tmp/mesos \
            -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
            -v /cgroup:/cgroup \
            -v /sys:/sys \
            -v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker \
            mesosphere/mesos-slave:1.3.0
```

But if I use `docker ps -q | xargs docker inspect --format '{{.State.Pid}}, {{.Name}}'`, it shows:

```
10511, /mesos-slave-58
25155, /mesos-slave-55
29144, /mesos-slave-52
12581, /mesos-slave-49
26998, /mesos-slave-46
10444, /mesos-slave-43
25230, /mesos-slave-40
8532, /mesos-slave-37
22994, /mesos-slave-34
6443, /mesos-slave-31
20917, /mesos-slave-28
3267, /mesos-slave-25
8972, /mesos-slave-22
23268, /mesos-slave-19
28523, /mesos-slave-16
1191, /mesos-slave-13
7570, /mesos-slave-10
11568, /mesos-slave-7
17134, /mesos-slave-4
20608, /mesos-slave-1
```

It seems that they are different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the "pids" column in your first output is the number of processes in the container, not any specific process's process ID.  Also remember when looking at this that each container starts up with its own pid space and the main process you start via `docker run` or a Dockerfile `CMD` is, within the container, process ID 1, with the rights and responsibilities that entails; but on the host a Docker container is "just" a process with some encapsulation and so it will have a distinct host pid.